# Write a route ('/form') that processes HTML form input

Tags: node.js, express

I am attending a workshop for nodejs and expressjs on nodeschool.io and came across this exercise but when I try out the solution it is not working.

I don't see any route being created for form.

The solution I found is:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

var bodyparser = require('body-parser');


app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.post('/form',function(req,res){
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/public/index.html'));
    res.send(req.body.str.split(" ").reverse().join(" "));
});

app.listen(Number(process.argv[2]));
```

Could anyone help me and tell me what is wrong with the solution provided?

Answer (score 1):

use an app.get request before the app.post request to get the form.

so it is like;

```
app.get('/form',function(){});
```

and then

```
app.post('/form',function(){});
```

Answer (score 0):

From the code you've provided, the route will be called on POST HTTP request. So that will be called after you submit your form and it is not responsible for any HTML rendering (if we leave the endpoint this way).

However, you can see there is a commented line, which would be the HTML rendering (perhaps the index.html file contains the form?). To get that work, you can make a new route

```
app.get('/form', ...)
```

which will return the HTML file and the form.

Comment: I commented that line to check if POST HTTP request was working or not. but when I uncomment it and run the script all I get is : Cannot GET /form. I wanted to use POST method instead of GET method.

Comment: You cannot use GET, as you use app.post function. Change it to app.get, and you should get the HTML back. Make a second function, app.post, where you are waiting for form submit.